# JQuery Scroll MoveTo.js plugin issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

i'm trying to add scrollTop button on my site, but i have one problem, i want add to this button one effect, like if scrollTop less then 50px, button will be invisible, how i can do this with JQuery?

***My Code:***
**HTML**

```
<a class="target" href="#" data-mt-duration="800"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></a>
```

**JS code**

```
const moveTo = new MoveTo({
  tolerance: 0,
  duration: 800,
  easing: 'easeOutQuart'
});

const trigger = document.getElementsByClassName('target')[0];

moveTo.registerTrigger(trigger);
```

MoveTo.JS plugin link:
https://github.com/hsnaydd/moveTo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scrollTop() in jQuery.
Use a comparison operator on the windows scroll position against another value, in your case 50px. Wrap it in a window.onscroll event.

```
  $(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var windowScrollTop = Math.floor($(window).scrollTop());
    if (windowScrollTop < 50) {
    // Hide button...
```

**jQuery API:**
https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

**Example:**
https://codepen.io/alexgill/pen/MBQyJe